# How to make a component that have an EditForm and encapsulate the form and the validation inside?

Tags: c#, blazor, asp.net-blazor

I want to make a component that have a `EditForm` and encapsulate the form and the validation inside of the component.

And I want to reuse this component anywhere in my application and submit it using any button.

How can I submit a `EditForm` from a button that is outside of it?

**Observation**: I have searched for other answers like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55976005/9119186) but the answer that is marked as accepted doesn't answer the question and that is why I'm making this new question.

Comment: IMO having a submit button outside a form is not a good idea...

Comment: Why do you want to create a this reusable component ? It sounds like you are reinventing the EditForm itself

Comment: Why don't you include the submit button in your component ?

Comment: Why everyone that ask this question, get comments like `Why you want to do this`? The reason why I want this is so I can edit an entity in multiple places of my app without having to rewrite the form everytime. And I don't want to include the submit button because in some cases the form will appear inside a modal and the submit button of that form will be the modal button

Comment: Just create the form whitout including the `EditForm` then. The `EditContext` is a Cascadind value.

Comment: And set the EditForm at page level

Comment: @aguafrommars If I do that, I won't be able to encapsulate the `OnValidSubmit`

Comment: Why not ? You OnValidSubmit handler can set a binded parameter of your reusable form component to trigger the submit code. Or you can get a ref of your component a call a method. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components?view=aspnetcore-3.1#capture-references-to-components

Comment: Oh, I didn't thought about that. So this is perfect, exactly what I wanted. Could you write that as an answer?

Comment: yes sure, I do it right now

Comment: If you just got here, you should take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61633966/9119186)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of including the `EditForm` in the component, create a component without the `EditForm` and call a component's method on `OnValidSubmit`

```cs
<EditForm OnValidSubmit="HandleValidSubmit">
    <FormContentComponent @ref="_formContent" />
    <button type="submit">submit</button>
</EditForm>
@code {
    private FormContentComponent _formContent;

    private void HandleValidSubmit()
    {
        _formContent.HandleValidSubmit();
    }
}
```