# How to programmatically submit a Blazor form?

Tags: c#, blazor, blazor-server-side

Having a Blazor [`EditForm`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/forms-validation?view=aspnetcore-3.1) and a contained `InputTextArea` (i.e. a multiline text box), I do want to validate and submit the form, when the user presses <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>, just as if he would click the submit button.

I've successfully got the keyboard handler connected like this:

```html
<EditForm Model="@myModel" Format="g" OnValidSubmit="@Store" @ref="_editForm">
    <InputTextArea 
        onkeypress="@(async e => await myKeyPress(e))"
        @bind-Value="myModel.Foo" />
    <button type="submit">Store it</button>
</EditForm>
```

With this code behind:

```cs
private EditForm _editForm;

private async Task myKeyPress(KeyboardEventArgs key)
{
    if (key.CtrlKey && key.Code == @"Enter")
    {
        _editForm.??? // What to call here?
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, I see no method in the EditForm class that I could call to submit *and* validate the form, as if the user would click the submit button.

I've looked at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60740060/107625) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55975262/107625) SO question with no success.

#### My question

How to programmatically submit and validate a Blazor form?

Comment: But suppose that the user has only pressed Enter after typing. This will also submit the form... Actually, the form always submits if an input control has the focus, and you hit enter. Think about that, and reformulate your question...

Comment: @enet Since it is an Input**TextArea** which ist a multiline control, pressing the `Enter` key simply puts the keyboard caret into the next line.

Comment: Yes, you're right. I did not put attention to this fact.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
<EditForm Context=MyCurrentEditContext>
  <InputTextArea 
        onkeypress="@(async e => await myKeyPress(MyCurrentEditContext, e))"
        @bind-Value="myModel.Foo" />
    <button type="submit">Store it</button>
</EditForm>

@code
{
private async Task myKeyPress(EditContext editContext, KeyboardEventArgs key)
{
    if (key.CtrlKey && key.Code == @"Enter")
    {
        if (editContext.Validate())
        {
          ... Do stuff if valid
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, Peter. This _nearly_ did the trick. Unfortunately, the InputTextArea has a validation on it that it must be non-empty. When this field has the input focus and the keyboard handler fires, the exchange between the textarea and the bound model field is not yet performed. I have to change the input focus forth and back first. I even tried calling`NotifyFieldChanged` without success. Any hint on whether/how to fill the model value even without a focus change?

Comment: OK, I solved it by deriving my own `InputTextArea` (like e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57326353/107625)) and adding an `oninput` handler, in addition to the `onchange` handler. In fact, I copied the code from [the original source](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/tree/master/src/Components/Web/src/Forms/InputTextArea.cs) and added the `oninput` handler. With this, the change is triggered not only when the focus is lost, but immediately.

Comment: @Uwe Keim, see this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62103477/6152891 This is, I believe, how you should have done it... Could you please post your solution here.

Comment: @UweKeim Try adding `@bind-Value:event="oninput"` to your `InputText`. Not certain it will work, but it might.

Comment: Thanks, @PeterMorris Your help here and your tons of tutorials and examples on your website helped and help me in an awesome lot of cases. Thank you very much for your efforts!

Comment: @UweKeim Did it work on `<InputText>` then? I thought it should, but I've never tried.

Comment: I did keep the solution with my `InputTextArea`-derived class, that was more straightforward to me.