# Blazor EditForm submit programatically

Tags: c#, blazor, blazor-webassembly

**Note :** this  is not a duplicate, although the title may be similar, my question is different from them.

I have a Blazor EditForm and want to submit it manually by code. For sake of some UI issues I don't want to put a submit button inside the form :

```
<EditForm  OnValidSubmit="ValidSubmit" OnInvalidSubmit="Invalid">
 ...
 <button type="submit" >Save</button> // <--- I don't want the button to be here. I want it to be placed somewhere else outside of Editform 
</EditForm>

@code{

    public void ValidSubmit()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("valid");
    }
    public void Invalid()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("invalid");
    }
}
```

I want the submit button to be placed somewhere else outside of Editform. Hacky ways like calling the click event of a invisible submit button inside the edit form are also be accepted.

Comment: You can get a reference to the form element and call `Submit()` on it with javascript.

Comment: @Crowcoder how? the edit form does not have a submit method.

Comment: EditForm has an AdditionalAttributes property which I assume you can use to set the html name of the form. Then you can use standard js or even do some blazor js interop: `document.getElementById("myForm").submit();`

Comment: @Crowcoder I tried both js.InvokeVoidAsync("document.getElementById('editForm').submit");  and also with parenteses at the end of submit method. And got getElementById is undefined.

Comment: I haven't actually used js invoke with Blazor, try just a plain vanilla js function or just execute that code in console to see if it works. You could also try document.querySelector but I imagine you would end up at the same place.

Comment: @Crowcoder I put the code in a another method then called that method and it executed but it submited and refreshed the whole page so this is not a way to do it.

Comment: If you don't want a page refresh then you don't want to "submit". You want to post the form. You could fight the framework and use ajax to do a post. Have you considered using css to place the button physically where ever you want while logically having it within the EditForm?

Comment: @Crowcoder, the page is refreshed because the submit button is misused. You can't post a form from Blazor. Http post request are not a concept of the Blazor framework. In Blazor, the submit action is always captured and canceled. "Have you considered using css to place the button physically where ever you want while logically having it within the EditForm?"  See here how to do that: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61633966/6152891

Comment: @enet That is why I said "fight the framework". I meant that to make it obvious I wasn't suggesting it as a good solution. You may as well not use Blazor if you are going to go around it that way.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to place submit button for a Blazor EditForm outside of the component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55975262/how-to-place-submit-button-for-a-blazor-editform-outside-of-the-component)

Comment: @enet good find.

Answer (score 1):

Next code shows a generic Blazor component that automatically posts a dictionary of string values to an external url as soon as the dictionary, the url and the JS runtime are all available:

```
@inject IJSRuntime JSRuntime

<form action="@Url" method="post" style="display:none">
    @if (Data != null)
    {
        @foreach (var item in Data ?? new Dictionary<string, string>())
        {
            <input type="hidden" name="@item.Key" value="@item.Value" />
        }
    }
    <input type="submit" value="submit" @ref="SubmitButton" />
</form>



@code {
    ElementReference SubmitButton;

    [Parameter] public string? Url { get; set; }
    [Parameter] public Dictionary<string, string>? Data { get; set; }

    protected override async Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender)
    {
        if (Data != null && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(Url))
        {
            await JSRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("triggerClick", SubmitButton);
        }
    }
}
```

In order for this to work you should insert a javascript function to programmatically click the form submit button on your _Host.cshtml just before importing _framework/blazor.server.js:

```
function triggerClick(elt) {
    elt.click();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use an `EditForm` property on the view as a reference to the form, then have a custom `@onclick` handler on the submit button.

```
<EditForm @ref="_editFormRef" OnValidSubmit="ValidSubmit" OnInvalidSubmit="InvalidSubmit" ... >
 ...
</EditForm>

<button @onclick="SubmitOnClick">Save</button>

@code{

    EditForm? _editFormRef;

    async Task SubmitOnClick()
    {
        if (_editFormRef.EditContext?.Validate() ?? false) {
            ValidSubmit();
        } else {
            InvalidSubmit();
        }
    }

    void ValidSubmit()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("valid");
    }
    void InvalidSubmit()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("invalid");
    }
}
```

Comment: `EditForm` doesn't have `ValidSubmit` or `Invalid` handlers to invoke. Did you test this code? it certainly doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 0):

I like Matias's answer, which works. But I would argue that we shouldn't be thinking in terms of HTML and JavaScript.

If you have a method that handles a valid submit call, you can call it directly from your blazor code. Just validate the form first. e.g.

```
<EditForm Model=_model @ref=_form OnValidSubmit=ValidSubmit>
...
</EditForm>
<button @onclick=ProgrammaticSubmit>Programmatic Submit</button>

@code {
    private EditForm? _form { get; set; }

    private void ProgrammaticSubmit()
    {
        if (_form.EditContext.Validate())
        {
            ValidSubmit();
        }
        else
        {
            Invalid();
        }
    }

    public void ValidSubmit()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("valid");
    }

    public void Invalid()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("invalid");
    }
}
```